# flask module import failure from test folder

Tags: python, flask

How do I import modules located up (out of a test folder) and then back down my app folder structure?

in the app_test.py folder I want to

```
from app.models import User
```

running

```
/bin/python app_test.py
```

I get

```
no modules named app.models
```

I have an app_test.py file that worked until i did some shuffling, and now i'm not sure why My imports are not working when running tests from my test folder.  I'm vitrualenv'd into my apps main folder and here's the basic layout minus superfluous folders/files:

```
/application

  /(leaving out folders bin build lib local...)
  /src
    /test
         __init__.py
         app_test.py
    /app 
         models.py
         forms.py
         __init__.py
         views.py
        /static
        /templates
        /tmp
```

What should my import be?  I notice that the mega tutorial just uses a test.py file instead of a folder.  is that the best way to do it, and if not, where should my test folder be located?   It is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You either need to run your app_test.py from the top, (ie, "python test/app_test.py") or fixup the python path in app_test.py:

```
import os
import sys
topdir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")
sys.path.append(topdir)
```

Comment: This took me a little to figure out, but make sure to import your flask app underneath these lines