# Flask - Can't import app inside test file

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I'm trying to write some unit tests for a flask application I made. The project is setup like this:

```
apiproject (parent folder containing everything)
 /venv
 run.py
 requirements.txt
 /project
   __init__.py
   /departments
     __init__.py
     routes.py
     models.py
   /users
     __init__.py
     routes.py
     models.py
   /tests
     TestUsers.py
```

run.py:

```
from project import app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

my actual app is created under project/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, Response
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask_cors import CORS

load_dotenv(verbose=False)

DB_URL = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")

# initialize the application
app = Flask(__name__)
```

and in my TestUsers.py I have this:

```
import json
from project import app
import unittest
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_env(verbose=False)

class TestUsers(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app
        self.url_prefix = prefix = os.getenv("URL_PREFIX")
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
    
    def test_index(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.url_prefix + '/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       unittest.main()
```

When I run TestUsers.py, I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'. I tried doing sys.path.append('../') and ../../ inside of TestUsers.py, but that didn't help.

Comment: move test in `/project` module. For reference https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/layout/

Comment: That didn't work :(

Comment: Sorry I meant moving it out and use relative path. I'm sure that will work

Comment: Add the path to the file to system path. You can do that at the top of your test file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside TestUsers.py, before importing app:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22737042/7858114
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an **init**.py in your apiproject folder too.